# Automatic GUI for python script with command line arguments?

Tags: python, user-interface, exe

Is there any software that auto generates GUI wrappers around python scripts?

My specific scenario is that i wrote a simple script for my father in law to bulk download some stuff from a given url.

Normally you just run the script via

`python my_script.py --url https://test.com --dir C:\Downloads`

and it just downloads all the relevant files from test.com to the Downloads folder.

I think he might be able to handle that but i am not sure and so i was thinking if there is any simple software out there that would allow me to take the script and turn it into an executable that just asks for all arguments and then has a simple `run` button to execute the script and download the things.

Ideally this would mean that he doesnt have to install python but at the very least allow for easier handling for him.

I am aware that there are libraries that allow for the creation of custom GUIs for python but thought that maybe there already exists something simpler and generic for my very simple and i also think fairly common use case.

Comment: If your Python script does not require any input and should be run on a regular basis, you can use PyInstaller or Py2exe to create a standalone executable. This executable can be configured to run automatically at predetermined intervals, such as every other day, without the need for any additional input or user intervention. PyInstaller and Py2exe are tools that allow you to package Python scripts as standalone executables, which can be run on a computer without requiring the user to install Python.

Comment: @Dexty it does require 2 but at the very least 1 argument as an input from the user.
Namely the directory to save the files to (this could be hard coded if necessary) but at the very list the url to download from as that will not be the same one every time.

Comment: What if you had a json file or something that the script checks before it's executed? It's not perfect, but at least you don't have to write a whole GUI setup.

Comment: What I might do is to not use command line arguments but instead use `input`. That way he does not have to use the CLI proactively but the executable opens it for him and asked for the url (after using pyinstaller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey). From the README:

```
from gooey import Gooey

@Gooey      <--- all it takes! :)
def main():
  parser = ArgumentParser(...)
  # rest of code
```

It parses the decorated function and looks for `argparse` declarations.

[image]

(I'm not affiliated with this project)

Comment: This is actually EXACTLY what i wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using PyInstaller (thanks @Dexty) and rewriting the script to grab the arguments by asking for them via `input`.

Not exactly a GUI but that still allows the user to just double click the `.exe` and go from there instead of having to proactively use a CLI.